# How to check if Cloud Pub/Sub emulator is up and running?

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I have GC functions which I develop and test locally by using Cloud Pub/Sub emulator.

I want to be able to check from within Go code if Cloud Pub/Sub emulator is up and running. If not, I would like to inform a developer that he/she should start emulator before he/she execute code locally.

When the emulator starts I noticed a line

> INFO: Server started, listening on 8085

Maybe I can check if port is available or similar.

Comment: The most robust way would be to try to send a message and see what you get. You can publish a "hello world" on some dummy topic, if you get a response "no such topic" you know the emulator is running. If you get a connection error, it's probably not. It's idiomatic to do these "pings", the stdlib even has the `Ping` method on `sql.DB` for this purpose

Comment: This is not the answer.
Code
 `topic := client.Topic("testTopic")

 topic.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
  Data: []byte("testString"),
 })`
does not returns any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have used this command:

```
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start
```

And you got the following output:

```
[pubsub] This is the Google Pub/Sub fake.
[pubsub] Implementation may be incomplete or differ from the real system.
[pubsub] 
[pubsub] INFO: IAM integration is disabled. IAM policy methods and ACL checks are not supported
[pubsub] 
[pubsub] INFO: Applied Java 7 long hostname workaround.
[pubsub] 
[pubsub] INFO: Server started, listening on 8085
```

If you take a look at the second `INFO` message you'll notice that the process name will be `JAVA`. Now you can run this command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

Getting all the listening ports and applications, the output should be something like this:

```
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

XXXX
XXXX
java    XXX  XXX    XX   IPv4  XXX      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:8085 (LISTEN)
```

Alternatively you can modify the previous command to show only what is happening on the desired port:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 8085
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems my question was not clear enough. I fixed it now. I need to check from within Go code. Although, this gives me some new ideas.

Comment: You could try using the [exec package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec) in order to execute shell commands, specifically [this](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) section.

Comment: Technically yes, but my boss will probably not like the approach.